# How to make two git repositories identical?

Tags: git

Scenario:

I have two git repositories called, `volatile` and `template` respectively.

`template` is a Read-Only repo that is treated as the "original".

Both `volatile` and `template` exist on multiple (atleast two) upstream remotes.

`volatile` starts out as an identical copy of `template`.
This is done by force pushing to `volatile` from inside `template` like so:

```
cd template;
git push -f remote-url1:volatile --prune
git push -f remote-url2:volatile --prune
```

After a few operations on volatile, the state of volatile changes.
Branches, tags and commits are added.

How do I go about making `volatile` identical to `template` (on the remotes) again?

---

I can currently reset branches by doing the following:

```
 # On my local machine
cd template;
git push -f remote-url1:volatile 'refs/remotes/origins/*:refs/heads/*' --prune
git push -f remote-url2:volatile 'refs/remotes/origins/*:refs/heads/*' --prune
```

I've tried using

```
cd template;
git push -f remote-url1:volatile --tags --prune
```

and

```
cd template;
git push -f remote-url1:volatile --prune 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

to remove tags added on the remote, but this seems to give mixed results (I can't delete tags at times, remote says everything is up to date)

Comment: Can you simply `git clone remote-url1:template volatile`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I do that locally, but I can't do that for the remotes.

Comment: Can you `rsync` to the remotes?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Unfortunately, I can't. If I had any sort of access to the underlying repositories at the remote, this question would be a moot one, I'd simply blow away the original repos, clone `template` and rename them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best bet seems to be:

```
cd template;
git push -f remote-url1:volatile 'refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/' --prune
git push -f remote-url1:volatile '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' --prune
```